# How to create one string from values from CSV file in bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a csv file and I need to read its values to one string.

This is what I have for now:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set FULL_STR=""
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("%CSV_PATH%") do (
    set !FULL_STR!=!FULL_STR!%%a%%b%%c
)
echo !FULL_STR!      //returns ""
```

Could anyone help me to do it?

Comment: `set !FULL_STR!=...` !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set FULL_STR=""
```

sets `FULL_STR` to `""`.

```
set "FULL_STR="
```

sets `FULL_STR` to *empty*.

```
set !FULL_STR!=!FULL_STR!%%a%%b%%c
```

sets a variable named [the current contents of `FULL_STR`] to [the current contents of `FULL_STR`][the two fields from the file]

```
set "FULL_STR=!FULL_STR!%%a%%b%%c"
```

sets the variable `FULL_STR` to `[the current contents of`FULL_STR`][the two fields from the file]`